# How can I allow a normal user to stop Postgresql on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, ubuntu-16.04

My user is 'peaagent'. I have tried `visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/peaagent` with the following:

```
peaagent ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl stop postgresql.service
```

When I try stop Postgresql as peaagent it prompts me for a password:

```
peaagent@myserver:~$ /bin/systemctl stop postgresql.service
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===
Authentication is required to stop 'postgresql.service'.
Authenticating as: root
Password:
```

Anyone know why this doesn't work? Tx.

Comment: What exactly happens, what error messages do you see, what relevant messages are there in your logs ?

Comment: I don't get an error, it just prompts me for a password which I don't want. Nothing in /var/log/syslog. Is there another log file I should be looking at?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not prefixing your command with `sudo`. As you are attempting to run a systemd command without sufficient privilege, systemd is asking for a password (via systemd-ask-password) to a suitably privileged account.

```
sudo  /bin/systemctl stop postgresql.service
```

should do what you want.

Comment: Duh! I knew I must be doing something stupid. Tx!

Comment: No it's not this